# Collect count from any missing data in rows from MySql

Tags: mysql

I currently have a counter that will give a total number of entries that is missing information for NAME in the database. I have 3 more fields for this (Name, Address, Phone, Email). I would like the count to show if any of that info is missing, not just the names. (below is what I have so far).

What I have is this

```
select count(ifnull(name,' ')) AS count FROM `customer` WHERE name IN (' ') != ' '
```

Another words, if I have for example the following, then the counter would say 3 and also only echo the ones that have the missing fields

```
| id | Name |   Address  |  Phone    |    Email     |
|----|------|------------|-----------| -------------|
| 1  | bob  |  123 main  | 555-5555  |  you@you.com |
| 2  |      |  123 main  | 555-5555  |  you@you.com |
| 3  | ann  |  123 main  |           |  you@you.com |
| 4  | tod  |            | 555-5555  |  you@you.com |
```

Comment: @your common sense, why did you edit this and remove the php tag? I am using php so that is why I put that in the tag, and what was wrong with my post that you had to edit it? I'm asking for future knowledge of posting

Comment: Because PHP has nothing to do with the SQL query. The query would be the same if you're processing the result in Python, JavaScript, etc.

Comment: Okay thanks. I thought I had to include that if that was the language I was using

Comment: Just use `SELECT COUNT(*)`, that will count the number of rows that meet the `WHERE` condition.

Comment: You only need it if it's relevant to the question.

Comment: @Barmar then how would I get it to count if any of those fields are missing and not just the name field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `COUNT(*)` to count the number of rows that meet the `WHERE` condition.

To count if any of the fields are missing, check them all in the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM customer
WHERE IFNULL(name, '') = '' or IFNULL(address, '') = '' or IFNULL(phone, '') = '' or IFNULL(email, '') = ''
```

Comment: Ahhhhhh so "or" allows multiple instances of it. Okay thank you much!

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working. I think it's because when they are blank it is not entering as NULL in the database. It's just a blank space

Comment: I've changed it to match either NULL or empty strings.

Comment: Ahhh even better! Thank you very much!